# VI freezes putty session whenever I try to edit a file even though no swap or processing using the file

Tags: ssh, vi

So I have this file that i've been editing, lets call it evilConfig.xml.

There are no processes running that is using it yet. I have edit it before, but today for some reason when I try to vi evilConfig.xml putty session freezes. VI doesn't even come up.

I can cat the file just fine.

What I've tried and has not worked:

1. Check for swap files (there was one from my other session, deleted it)
2. cat the file to test. rm evilConfig.xml; vi test works!; mv test evilConfig.xml DOESNT!!
3. pray to the vi god for forgiveness of my sins

Any other ideas?

Why can I cat evilConfig.xml > test; vi test; but when I mv test evilConfig.xml and try vi evilConfig.xml, I get a line break and ssh session stops responding.

I don't see any funky characters when I cat it either.

Thanks guys (and gals),

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the file name. When I move the file to /tmp and try to vi it there, still freezes. i can rename it in temp to /tmp/wtf.xml and try vi wtf.xml it works. The name of the file is not anything weird or special and I have edited it before many times and still works on other similar Debian hosts.

Comment: Before i read your comment, i was assuming something to do with the .xml extension. What version of vi are we talking about? Which operating system?

Comment: @dlite922 As you believe it has something to do with the filename, what's the real name of the file?

Comment: Do you have any vim plugins for xml files?  Try "vim --noplugin yourFile.xml" and see if that helps.  Also, you might override your vimrc with the -u option to see if that helps.  If it's a large file, you might be running into trouble there, too.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys, it started working after the weekend. There are no plugins for XML. File is not large. Not sure what the deal was, but I can't troubleshoot anymore without the problem.edit: filename was called vct_gen.xml. nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run vi (actually vim) with the -X option.

Its an old post but I ran in a very similar problem. My Putty freezes sometimes when starting vim. I am sitting in front of a Windows 7 PC with X-server running and X11 forwarding enabled in putty. The PC is connected to a remote IBM Power6 with AIX. After such a freeze I looked in Event log in Putty and I noticed that the last action was a  "Requesting X11 forwarding". Vim connects to your X server in order to use the clipboard and to change the window title. Setting the -X option made that my putty doesn't freezes anymore in this situations.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in large MTU size. You can change MTU on router if you using NAT, but I change MTU on server:

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 mtu 1036
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

On Windows you can also increase this key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"TcpMaxDataRetransmissions"=dword:00000010
```